# HTML errors, <body> is only part of the page

Tags: html, css

I am editing a website as a favour to a professor, and I was very surprised to see the site in a very bad shape (or so I think). It's been a long time since i've edited HTML and CSS, and I couldn't understand how this was happening.

This is the link to the website: http://bioclues.org/ojs/index.php/IJCB/index
And here is what I think is wrong: http://bayimg.com/kAnaIaaDi

I was making it a little better looking, and wanted to enclose the headers, content, etc in a single div so that I could get a blog-ish look. But this was weird.

Any help on why this is happening? And how do I correct it?

The system being used is Open Journal Systems.

Comment: I don't understand the question, :S

Comment: Are you asking about <div id="body"> ? and can you specify what exactly you want? i can solve these issues very quickly ...

Comment: No, i'm talking about the main body tag.

Comment: Dear body tag is showing in view source. Problem is with your Css and just a min i m going to post some css rules you jst change it and your page will be fine.

Comment: Saikios: I had learnt that all the elements which are in the body tag will consist of what we will see. But here, some of the elements are outside the body in spite of them being inside the body tag.

Comment: Happy Singh: Thank you. Could you tell me where the code is wrong? It's been a long time since i've done anything related to the web.

Comment: see my answer and try the css mention. Let me know if any issues so i can change as per your need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The picture is gone, by the way.

My guess is that your problem is incorrect nested tags.  Use an HTML editor to avoid those errors.  Or just use notepad++

**EDIT:**

Ok I think I figured the problem there

in leftSidbe.css line 37

```
#main {
  /*float: right;*/
  width: 63%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
}
```

Commenting float and overflow will show you your body.  Something like that is also covering the left nav.

Comment: I can still see the picture. It's still there.

Comment: Yes, this seems to have corrected it. Thanks a lot! What was the problem though, may I ask?

Comment: http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2005/03/clearing_floats.html this should explain how they work together

Answer (score 1):

Change the below css with you existing css -

Css line 106 common.css

```
#headerTitle {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    /*text-align: left !important;*/
    width: 100%;
}

Common.css line  113

#header h1 {
    font-family: Georgia,'Times New Roman',Times,serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0.5em;
}

common line 152

#navbar {
    border-bottom: 2px dotted #000000;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-bottom: 0.5em;
    text-align: center;
}

leftsidebar.css line 20

#body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 950px;
}
```

Screen shot: http://bayimg.com/LANaNAadi

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it in an hour and a half after class and let you know.

Comment: No problem.. take your time and i jst add screen shot for you reference.

Answer (score 0):

The body label on the screen is belong to a div which has an id with value "body".

Comment: I believe it's showing the main body tag. It shows the div label as div#body.